# Unexpected behavior with removeAttachmentAsync() in OfficeJs

Tags: jquery, outlook-addin, office-js

I have just run into some unexpected behavior with `removeAttachmentAsync()` in OfficeJs. Up until recently (few weeks) the functionality was consistent and worked for our case, then we seem to be seeing something odd happening.

So a little background we have a button to add an attachment through `addFileAttachmentAsync()` on a compose page, we then save the attachment_id to the session for future use and then the button logic reversed to use `removeAttachmentAsync()` to remove said attachment with the saved attachment_id in the session. Keep in mind when we add the attachment, we wait and verify that the attachment has been fully added before the user can do anything else. The user then has the option to go to a settings page.

Verification that attachment was added successfully:

```
status: "succeeded"
value: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" // ${attachment_id}
```

This is where things get interesting, if the user adds an attachment then goes to the settings page, then returns to our compose page, and chooses to remove the attachment we get this error but the attachment is being removed by OfficeJs:

```
error: Object { name: "AttachmentDeletedBeforeUploadCompletes",
   message: "The user removed the attachment before upload has completed.",
   code: 9006 }
   status: "failed"
   value: null
```

However below is the DeleteAttachment action that OfficeJS executes against the Exchange server:

URL: https://exchange.server.com/owa/service.svc?action=DeleteAttachment&ID=-481&AC=1
Response:

```
{
    "Body":{
        "ResponseMessages":{
            "Items":[
                {
                    "__type":"DeleteAttachmentResponseMessage:#Exchange",
                    "ResponseCode":"NoError",
                    "ResponseClass":"Success",
                    "RootItemId":{
                        "RootItemChangeKey":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "RootItemId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx="
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This behavior is not consistent the Exchange server says success and OfficeJs says failed.

Below is my code for removal of the attachment:

```
      function remove() {
            $.ajax({
              url: "/getattachment",
              dataType: 'json',
              cache: false
            }).always(function(res) {
              if(res.id) {
                Office.context.mailbox.item.removeAttachmentAsync(res.id,{asyncContext: null}, function (asyncResult) {
                    // Display the result to the user
                    if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                      if (typeof Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages === 'undefined') {
                        sidepane_status('success', 'Attachment removed.');
                      } else {
                        update_status('encryption-off', 'Attachment removed..');
                      }
                      attachment_id = null;
                    } else {
                      sidepane_status('error', 'Unable to remove attachment: ' + asyncResult.error.message);
                    }
                  }
                );
              } else {
                sidepane_status('error', 'Unable to remove attachment: ' + asyncResult.error.message);
              }
            });
          }
```

In the MS docs i see:

"In Outlook Web App and OWA for Devices, the attachment identifier is valid only within the same session. A session is over when the user closes the app, or if the user starts composing in an inline form and subsequently pops out the inline form to continue in a separate window."

But in this case the user is not closing the app, is still using the same session, and not composing an inline form.

Anyone know what may have changed recently or any insights into what may be happening?

TLDR; Called `removeAttachmentAsync()`, attachment was removed but OfficeJs returns failed because "The user removed the attachment before upload has completed.".

Update 1: Attachment code

```
function add() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/attachment",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false
  }).done(function(response) {
    if(typeof response.attachment_name !== "undefined" && typeof response.attachment_url !== 'undefined') {
      Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync(response.attachment_url, response.attachment_name, { asyncContext: null }, function(asyncResult) {
          if(asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            if(typeof Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages === 'undefined') {
              sidepane_status('success', 'Attachment successfully added');
            } else {
              update_status('encryption-on', 'Attachment successfully added.');
            }
            attachment_id = asyncResult.value;
            $.ajax({
              url: "/saveattachment/" + attachment_id,
              dataType: 'json',
              cache: false
            }).always(function() {
              // Hide an Element
            });
          } else {
            sidepane_status('error', 'Unable to add attachment: ' + asyncResult.error.message);
          }
        }
      );
    } else {
      sidepane_status('error', 'Unable to retrieve attachment information');
    }
  });
}
```

Keep in mind the user adds an attachment with `add()`, we save the attachment id, the user goes to a new page through a hyperlink and returns through another hyperlink. Since we save the attachment id we then use it to remove the attachment with `remove()`.

Comment: We are unable to reproduce this issue. Thanks for sharing the removeAttachmentAsync code. Can you share the addFileAttachmentAsync code as well to help us investigate this issue end-to-end?

Comment: Updated with attachment addition code, and some more context to reproduce.

Comment: Unfortunately we still aren't able to repro with our simple test cases, which leads us to believe that something is unique with your add-in. Can you either provide your add-in, or give a very simple test case that repros the problem? Also in case it matters, does this repro on every browser or just the certain browsers? is it a 100% repro as well?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Not a problem, could you possible ping me with either a Github or Bitbucket user id so I may add you to the private repo. I rather not post the whole add-in on the open internet, I hope you understand.

Comment: Also, It's not 100% reproducible, but probably a good 80% of the time. However, It's only happening in OWA, and it appears to be browser agnostic.

Comment: Our gitHub username is exextoc.  If you share the private repo we can take a look.